# Automatically identifying functions that can be parametrically polymorphic

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, agda

Is there method - based on, e.g. analysis of recursive structure or other static analysis - to identify functions that could be made parametrically polymorphic?

For instance, if I had mistakenly written

```
reverse :: [Int] -> [Int]
reverse []     = []
reverse (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
```

this optimization would correct the type signature to

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```

My guess is that this sort thing is fairly standard, but I haven't found the right thing to Google. Can someone pass on a reference?

Comment: It is already in the Haskell compiler. If you simply write the implementation, in ghci you can use `:t reverse` and it will calculate the most generic signature possible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is that just figured out as a side effect of the type checking? Also, is there a term for the optimization - broadening or something like that?

Comment: in essence, yes. Haskell will have to derive the type of each expression, etc. and thus also from functions in order to typecheck the program. The type signature is not mandatory (with some exceptions for sophisticated *extensions* to the Haskell language). It is only a good practice to at least do this for the top level functions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think `:t` is slightly different to what OP is looking for. `:t` simply gives the type of a function, so if I’ve defined `reverse :: [Int] -> [Int]` then `:t reverse` will give `[Int] -> [Int]`. But I concur that type inference is the way to go here — leave the type signature off the function, and _then_ one can use `:t` (or some other method for doing the same thing) to get the inferred type.

Comment: You would think you'd always want whatever parametric polymorphism you can get. Sadly, that's not quite true, because of a nasty language feature called `seq` and an important GHC optimization called the worker-wrapper transformation. GHC can end up compiling type-specialized code *differently* from parametrically polymorphic code if `seq` is used. *sigh*